# PrintDocument not printing correct font size in Printing Paper

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using PrintDocuemnt class to printing records.At run time I am providing fontsize but I getting small size of letter on printing paper.

Function 1:Which calling CreateCheckFormatForCheckWriter method with Details object objTCWLDetailLayout and Current selected object

```
List<Image> StringToPrint=new List<Image>;    
Image objInput = objCWLayout.CreateCheckFormatForCheckWriter(objTCWLDetailLayout,       objCWPrintCheck);                
 StringToPrint.Add(objInput);
```

Function 2:Which call method CreateCheckFormatForCheckWriter()

```
Image objCheckImage1 = null;
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics(); // edited by jeet - assigned this.CreateGraphics()    
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;  
Brush P = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
Draw_Check8_StringCompName(objGlobalRulerbitmapData, g, P, i, objCWPrintCheck.ChkCompanyName);
```

Function 3:Call Draw_Check8_StringCompName() method

```
 private void Draw_Check8_StringCompName(List<TCWLDetail> objGlobalRulerbitmapData, Graphics g, Brush P, int i, string strVal)
        {
            try
            {
                string fontFace = ("Vedana");
                int fontSize = 6;
                Font drawFont = new Font(fontFace, fontSize);
                float XCB = horizontalRuler.ScaleValueToPixel(objGlobalRulerbitmapData[i].FX);
                float YCB = verticalRuler.ScaleValueToPixel(objGlobalRulerbitmapData[i].FY);
               // float YCB = verticalRuler.ScaleValueToPixel((objGlobalRulerbitmapData[i].FY <=(float) 0.1 ?(float) 0.325 : objGlobalRulerbitmapData[i].FY));
                string sTemp = strVal;
                g.DrawString(sTemp, drawFont, P, XCB, YCB);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
                cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

And Finally We set image on PrintDocument.StringToPrint is List type collection.

```
 private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {    //Set image from StringToPrint collection
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(StringToPrint[PageCounter], 6, 12, 816, 1256);                
                //PageCounter++;
                //e.HasMorePages = (PageCounter != StringToPrint.Count);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
                cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the [PaperSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not the actual font size itself. Either you didn't provide the code which draws the text on your `PrintDocument`, or the font (type/size/etc) is never set. If you use [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to draw text, you can set the font (and its size).

Comment: i updated my actual code where i was using Graphics.DrawString().see my updated code

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line where `drawFont` is set? Which font size is passed on to the constructor there? Also, what is the value of `i` ?

Comment: FontSize is 6 and Fontface is "Verdan".objGlobalRulerbitmapData[i] it collection object which hold data.i is int type value.

Comment: Well, a font size of 6 is very small (try it out in a text processor like Microsoft Word). Try setting it to 12.

Comment: i was test with text file.i was create a text file with same font and fontface and print it out.I got correct font size printing.but when i was using above code it was not working fine.

Comment: When you use a general text file (like a .txt file), there is no font or font size you can set, so it'll always be in a readable size (the software opening the text file handles that). Really, a font size of 6 is very small, just try setting `int fontSize = 12;`, it'll make a difference.

Comment: all fontsize and fontface are coming form database.so we can not change fontsize and fontface.if database contain fontsize 6 then user should get print with fontsize 6.

Comment: Then the correct font size is printed. Consider updating the database to contain larger font sizes or setting a minimum font size. Have you at least tried setting it manually to test if your code works the way you want it to?

Comment: i was already test this.font are coming fontsize with 12.But main issue is if layout in databse are contian 6 fontsize.because my requirement we can not change database and it hold 6 fontsize.i am stuck with font 6.

Comment: Then your question isn't correct, because the font is printed correctly, it's just a very small font size that is provided. You should discuss this requirement with the people who wrote it. Honestly, that is pretty much all I can do for you.